# Setting up email system in not successful

Tags: asp.net

Email setup in my webpage does not work. I have linked the email code to a button . when I link the button it keep also processing the web page without any error or hiccup. Increasing time out also does not help.

- Tried increasing timed out
- Tried adding system.net setting in web.config

```
//From Address 
string FromAddress = "a@x.com";
string FromAdressTitle = "Email from ASP.NET Core 1.1";
//To Address 
string ToAddress = "b@x.com";
string ToAdressTitle = "Microsoft ASP.NET Mail System";
string Subject = "Email";
string BodyContent = "ASP.NET Core was previously called ASP.NET 5. It was renamed in January 2016. It supports cross-platform frameworks ( Windows, Linux, Mac ) for building modern cloud-based internet-connected applications like IOT, web apps, and mobile back-end.";

//Smtp Server 
string SmtpServer = "email.bsnconnect.com";
//Smtp Port Number 
int SmtpPortNumber = 587;

var mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();
mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(FromAdressTitle, FromAddress));
mimeMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(ToAdressTitle, ToAddress));
mimeMessage.Subject = Subject;
mimeMessage.Body = new TextPart("plain")
{
    Text = BodyContent
};

using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
{
    client.Connect(SmtpServer, SmtpPortNumber, false);
    // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication 
    // Error 5.5.1 Authentication  
    client.Authenticate("a@x.com", "password1");
    client.Send(mimeMessage);
    Console.WriteLine("The mail has been sent successfully !!");
    Console.ReadLine();
    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

The error message reads:

> System.IO.IOException: 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'

Comment: Read the docs [SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8) and the important yellow box at top and the blue important box under remarks.

Comment: You should better use https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/

Comment: Error message : System.IO.IOException: 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'